# Transfert sql data to Azure DB

Tags: sql, azure

I've never worked with Azure DB.

My question is that I wrote an sql script witch result is 'two rows and 11 columns'. I have to send this result to an external Azure BD. I have the URL. I don't know how to do it.

Can someone help me with suggestions or provide me with internet links.

Thanks in advance.
Lina

Comment: Could you please provide some more information along with your SQL script?

Comment: It's a result of a long select (including many join , and union...).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside Azure portal, there is some sort of UI where you can paste your script and execute it in new DB, but you have to have access to it or...use MS SQL Server Management Studio, there use your url to connect. If you defined some authorization, you should provide it when creating initial conneciton.

Comment: I don't have access to the Azure BD. It's external to my organization.

Comment: Do you have a connection string? If it is not authorized use MS SQL Server Management Studio to connect and execute the script, if they will require some authorization...you will have to request that from admin.

Comment: I have an URL starting with : 'https://  ' .

Comment: How to connect to the URL with MS SQL Server Management Studio ?